# Linux HPLIP mess after installation of the drivers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cleaning, hplip

I have purchased HP OfficeJet 4500 Wireless. In order to install it, i followed the instructions for installing HPLIP here: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html
Everything installed fine, and the printer and the scanner are working !

But i ran the hplip-3.11.5.run file from my home directory. And now when i look at my home directory is full with soooo many files and directories, like 100 files *.lo and and some unknowns directories like pcard and more ...

I really liked my home directory to nice and clean.

I don't know if i can delete those files (probably not) or how can i move them to somewhere else ...

I am using xubuntu (10.04 LTS).

Thanks.

Comment: Why am I not surprised... (re HP, not you)

Comment: @Ignacio OT, but I've generally had good luck with HPLIP. @Aviv Try installing it via your package manager.

Comment: @new123456: Via package manager, sure. But HP has a very mixed history with regards to their drivers regardless of OS. Even now, I still don't know which path it downloads printer firmware to.

Comment: (First, thank you all for the comments) Meanwhile i have created another directory (called it hplip-deleted) and i moved all the files to this directory. Meanwhile everything still works fine. If i will try to use something and it will be broken i will take it out to same place it was before. That's way i will be able to check if those file are really needed. If you have more information, please share. 10x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as the comment by @aviv says (and that should have been an answer), its safe to delete those files.

I'd add that in general, its a good idea to use a working directory to do such things. It looks like it was a script that downloaded and extracted the source, compiled and linked things (which explains the lo files - which are libtool objects  ) and was nowhere well mannered enough to clean up after itself.

The instructions seem to indicate its *supposed* to create a folder for itself, extract the source, and basically do the equivilent of build-dep, grab the deps, make and make install the files. Other than barfing files all over the place it seems to have done something any power user would.

Assuming its just a standard build, running make clean in the folder might have cleaned things up, since it deletes all the linked files, assuming everything was just left there. Would have made life somewhat easier.